# Two heroku apps but use the same github

Tags: github, heroku

I'm currently building a website with like version 1 and version 2. Is it possible for me to create a new heroku app for version 2 and still use the same github master branch for it?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Are you deploying via `git push` or GitHub integration?

Comment: I am deploying via git push

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#creating-a-staging-environment